# Convert part of an ArrayBuffer to a string

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer

I have a C# App that, using WebSockets sends an ArrayBuffer to my Javascript client.
The 1st 2 byte are int values (8 bit).

The next 17 bytes represent a string of 17 chars.

The rest is an image array.

Now, I can read the 1st 2 bytes to get my ints.
I can also read the image.
How do I read the string value which starts from the 2 index (using base index of 1) and the following 17 bytes?

So, my code so far is:

```
var len = e.data.byteLength;
var dv = new DataView(e.data);
var liveViewIndex = dv.getInt8(0);
var tripped = dv.getInt8(1);
//need to get 17 char string here!!
var frame = e.data.slice(19, len - 19);
desktopImage.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64ArrayBuffer(frame);
```

thanks

Comment: What is `base64ArrayBuffer`?

Comment: Doesn't your [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/slice) call work?

Comment: Hi, it is just a function I found online that converts the ArrayBuffer to base64. It is not part of the question in the real-sense I was just keen show I have done some code. But, will post function if you like? :)

Comment: Slice - yes it does. My image appears so it must do

Comment: Oh, I see now, you want to read the string from `e.data.slice(2, 19)`, I confused the string with the image. But how is the string encoded?

Comment: I convert the string to a byte array using c# and that is sent via websockets to Javascript which reads the whole lot as an ArrayBuffer

Comment: Yeah, sure, but I meant the string encoding. Is it an ASCII string? UTF-8? Something else? You might be looking for [`StringView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/StringView)

Comment: apologies, it is ASCII

Comment: That is a cool link. Out of interest is there an alternative to convert the ArrayBuffer to base64 using these libraries as opposed to how I am doing it at the moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the string is encoded as simple ASCII, the following should work:

```
var string = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, new Uint8Array(e.data, 2, 17));
```

It first creates a [`Uint8Array` view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) on the interesting part of the buffer, and then [uses it as arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).

Comment: Uh, wait, do you mean this code gave you a bluescreen?

Comment: lol no!  It was not that potent. I am testing with a micro PC and it gets too hot in this weather and so needs rebooting every now and again. I did not want you to think I was rude by not replying in a timely fashion :)

Comment: Oh, really no offense taken - SO comments are not a real-time chat (even though responses *can* come really fast). Take your time.

Comment: works for me - thanks. I shall repost the question relating to converting ArrayBuffer to Blob using DataView.. Thanks for your answer

Comment: So far I can only tell you that the `Blob` constructor will take buffers as argument, though afaik it doesn't do any base64 encoding for you. But yes, this is really better asked as a second question.